# Div Cannot Wrap Alternating Images

Tags: html, css, user-interface

Couldn't solve it by myself so I've decided to use the help of the UI hackers.

I'm trying to do a simple design by creating a **div**, inserting an image (which will stay in left, **larger** than the second pic), then a text (basically including text with **p's**), then a small picture on right. Text wraps image on left just fine but the problem is that the image on right is **not** wrapped by the picture.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style='overflow:hidden;width:600px;border:1px solid black;padding:5px;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;'>
    <img src='../images/monkey.jpg' style='margin-right:7px;border:1px solid #C0C0C0;padding:5px;float:left;height:100px;width:125px;'/>
    <div style='word-wrap:break-word;'>
         this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual,this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life.this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life..This is the first paragraph to demonstrate how awesome-ly our products being built. Like w/e this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual,this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life.this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life..This is the first paragraph to demonstrate how awesome-ly our products being built. Like w/e this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual,this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life.this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life..This is the first paragraph to demonstrate how awesome-ly our products being built. Like w/e <img src='../images/monkey.jpg' style='margin-right:7px;border:1px solid #C0C0C0;padding:5px;float:right;height:50px;width:60px;'/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Um, please edit your code yourself.

Comment: There is no code apart from the html tag?

Comment: Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @Scott http://jsfiddle.net/uR34H/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually is working fine, you just need to put your image higher in the text.  I removed the div wrapper and placed the image higher and it works:

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/uR34H/1/)***

### HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style='overflow:hidden;width:600px;border:1px solid black;padding:5px;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;word-wrap:break-word;text-align:justify'>
        <img src='../images/monkey.jpg' style='margin:7px;border:1px solid #C0C0C0;padding:5px;float:left;height:100px;width:125px;'/>
        this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life.this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life..This is the first paragraph to demonstrate how awesome-ly our products being built. Like w/e this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual,this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life.this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life..This is the first paragraph to demonstrate how awesome-ly our products being built. 
        <img src='../images/monkey.jpg' style='border:1px solid #C0C0C0;padding:5px;float:right;height:50px;width:60px;margin:7px;'/> 
        Like w/e this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual,this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life.this is the second paragraph that has not even made it to the actual, live, brutal online life..This is the first paragraph to demonstrate how awesome-ly our products being built. Like w/e.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Output:

[image: jsFiddle demo screenshot]